# Ktor Client: parent property in Resources with nested classes

Tags: kotlin, ktor

In ktor client 2.0.2 docs, on Resources with neseted classes [section](https://ktor.io/docs/type-safe-request.html#resource_nested), it is stated:

> Nested classes should have a property with an outer class type.

From an example [Here](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-plugins/ktor-client-resources/io.ktor.client.plugins.resources/-resources/index.html)

```kotlin
@Serializable
@Resource("/users")
data class Users {
  @Serializable
  @Resource("/{id}")
  data class ById(val parent: Users = Users(), val id: Long)

  @Serializable
  @Resource("/add")
  data class Add(val parent: Users = Users(), val name: String)
}

// client-side
val newUserId = client.post(Users.Add("new_user")) // "/users?name=new_user"
val addedUser = client.get(Users.ById(newUserId)) // "/user/123"
```

We can see that `parent` property is unused in the code. Why do we need to initialize that as said?

Answer (score 0):

The property for the parent resource indicates that a child resource's path should be combined with a parent's path. The nesting organization of classes is optional.